# Python script to count number of files in a folder based on matching string within the files

Tags: python, bash, perl

I have a folder containing multiple files. I want to count the number of files that contains matching text say "Pathology" or a pattern say "ORC|||||xxxxxxxx||||||" inside it from those files present inside the folder. I have tried following scripts :

```
import re, os
import glob

list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.hl7')

for fileName in list_of_files:
    fin = open( fileName, "r" )
    count = 0

for line in fin:
    if re.match("Pathology", line):
            count +=1
fin.close()

print count
```

This gives me result as 0. I am using python 2.6.6. and have no options of upgrading my python. Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Why don't you just use `grep -l "Pathology\|ORC" *.hl7` ??

Comment: Why does this question have a Perl tag?

Comment: how if you use like `if 'Pathology' in line:..count +=1`? Also why every time you make `count=0` for each file? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162711/find-one-file-out-of-many-containing-a-desired-string-in-python

Comment: Please look at the question and make sure the indentation of the code is correct.

Comment: Where is the perl code?

Answer (score 1):

If you will accept a Perl solution then this fits the bill.

As it stands it prints the names of all the matching files. If you really want just the count then remove the line `print $ARGV, "\n"`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local @ARGV = glob './*.hl7';

my $count;

while (<>) {
  next unless /Pathology/i;
  ++$count;
  print $ARGV, "\n";
  close ARGV;
}

print "\n\n$count files found\n";
```

Comment: Can I check whether a line begins with ORC and the length of that line is atleast 10 then count otherwise not

Comment: @Debarshi: So you want to count the number of files that contain at least one record beginning `ORC` that has at least ten characters?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `grep` and `wc`:

```
grep Pathology *.hl7 | wc -l
```

gives you the number of hits.

```
grep -c Pathology *.hl7
```

will list the files with hits and then the number of hits per file.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to just use `grep --files-with-matches StringOrPattern *.hl7` or `grep -l StringOrPattern *.hl7` but if you need to do it in python you need to fix your indentation as your current code as posted will only report the number of matches in the last file.

```
import re, os
import glob

list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.hl7')
files_with_matches = 0

for fileName in list_of_files:
    fin = open( fileName, "r" )
    count = 0

    for line in fin:
        if re.match("Pathology", line):
            count +=1
    fin.close()

    if count > 0:
        files_with_matches += 1
        print filename, count

print "Done", files_with_matches, "Matches"
```